# How to give alert message after all form validation is complete?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, alert

After the submit button for my form is clicked the function formvalidtion() is executed from a javascript file, below.

```
function formValidation() {
    var fname = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
    var lname = document.getElementById('lastName').value;
    var pnumber = document.getElementById('phoneNumber').value;
    var email = document.getElementById('e-mail').value;

    return FirstName(fname) && LastName(lname) && PhoneNumber(pnumber) && Email(email) && thankyou();
  return false;
}
```

Example of individual validation.

```
function FirstName(fname) {
  var message = document.getElementsByClassName("error-message");
  var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
  if ( fname =="" || fname.match(letters)) {
    text="";
    message[0].innerHTML = text;
    return true;
  }
  
  else {
    text="First name should contain only letters";
    message[0].innerHTML = text;
    return false;
  }
}
```

As noted in the function formvalidtion() I have the function thankyou() referenced which is below.

```
function thankyou() {
    if (formValidation() === true){
        alert("Thank you for subscribing!");
    }
}
```

The rest of the validation functions are working not this though, the acknowledgement alert is not appearing. TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You send your function into a recursive pattern without a base case by allowing two functions call themselves(formValidation and thankYou). You can fix this by removing the conditional in the thankYou function

```
function thankyou() {
    alert("Thank you for subscribing!");
}
```

Comment: This solution displays the alert regardless if the form been completed or not i.e. empty form still gives the alert, I only want this alert once the form is completed correctly.

Comment: Did you test it? It should only alert if all the validations run successfully

Comment: Yea runs successfully only bug is that if the form is empty and you submit it gives the alert.

Comment: Then the problem is from your validation logic.. For example, in your Fname logic, I can see that for an empty string, you return true

Comment: Silly me haven't accounted for empty fields, thank you Kevin bless you mate!